# simulating Stack Overflow smooth vote operation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm wondering how can google translator (translate.google.com) save user rate without postback, also there are similar behaviors else where (for instance in Stack Overflow) where user views no postback (everything is so fast and smooth) but there is some database interaction, for instance voting questions/answers or comments in Stack Overflow, is it Ajax? or it is just JavaScript? It is really nice, how can I implement these type of operations using VS2010,C#, ASP.NET?

thanks

Comment: Yep, it's AJAX. Which is basically a technique in Javascript. Can't help you implement it in C# tho

Comment: You mean how the page updates without a refresh?  As *a guess*, "ajax long polling".  Basically, the client sends a request, but the server waits until something happens to reply, then the client sends another "long poll" request and the server hangs onto that, ad infinitum.

Comment: well I know Ajax, I've worked with it, but I wonder how fast is it performed!

Comment: It happens as fast as it needs to happen -- see my previous comment, I elaborated that.  Ie, the client **does not** send every two or five seconds or something.  Google "long poll".

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: It's as fast as any round-trip to the server.

Comment: @T.J Crowder: wrong.  It's the duration between one update and the next; ie, not instantaneous.  The request is sent, but the reply (round trip) may be any amount of time, seconds or minutes later.  That's presuming SO uses a long poll, which it may not...

Comment: ok I think I'm getting something, thanks for your quick answers

Comment: @goldilocks: I don't follow you. I said *"It's as fast as any **round-trip** to the server."* You said *"...ie, not instantaneous...the reply (round trip) may be any amount of time, seconds or minutes later."* I never said it was instantaneous, nor did I say it was fast. I said it was **as** fast as any other round-trip, which is true. (And in SO's case, it's normally very fast indeed, though sometimes things get a bit slow.)

Comment: What I meant was, it's not intended to be fast (and is probably much slower than any other round trip), the client is intended to be left waiting for an indeterminate period of time.  Eg, you have explained how, if you do something **active**, an ajax request is sent to the server.  This does not explain how the display is continuously updated when you are sitting doing nothing but reading, which is what I think the question is about.  It could be an intermittent poll at intervals (in which case each one takes place quickly) or a long poll (it which case it takes however long).

Comment: @goldilocks: That's not how I read the question: *"...save user rate without postback..."* That's an active action. *"... for instance voting questions/answers or comments in Stackoverflow..."* Again, that's an active action.

Comment: *"but there is some database interaction, for instance voting questions/answers or comments in Stackoverflow"* seems ambiguous that way to me, since it does not say, "When **I** vote or make a comment", and might include the updating that occurs when **someone else** voted or commented.  That requires some form of polling or web sockets, I think ;)

Comment: @goldilocks: Yes, *that* does, but to me the question is about voting, not about seeing votes occur in the background.

Comment: of course I think the whole thing can be done using other approaches as well, calling a web service from Java, although it is risky and users can manually call my web service, is there any way that my web service can be called only from my JS? so that users cannot it call it?

Comment: please excuse me for asking a general and somehow unclear question! I meant the whole process, i.e. when user click on vote icon which certainly involves some DB and server interaction

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: *"is there any way that my web service can be called only from my JS? so that users cannot it call it?"* No, you have to treat all data sent from the client as suspect. It can be spoofed in about a dozen ways (in the browser, in a tool that looks like a browser, by a man-in-the-middle proxy, ...).

Comment: For posterity: the passive updates do not use ajax at all; they use **web sockets**.  This is initiated with a request to something like `sockets.ny.stackoverflow` on load.  So when you see "1 new answer to this question" appear, that's where it came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Overview

Two aspects of this:

- When you do something that needs to be recorded on the server
- When you're just looking at things and notice that stuff updates even though you didn't do anything (the vote indicators change, you see things like "this post has been revised, click to load", "This question has been closed, no more answers will be accepted.", etc.)

#### When you do something that needs to be recorded server-side (e.g., vote)

It's JavaScript code sending ajax messages to the server. The server end of the conversation can be implemented with any technology you like (one of the joys of the web, the client and server sides are decoupled). Specifically, the page is loaded with the vote information as it was then, and when you click the vote button, the JavaScript code updates the vote display *immediately*, and then afterward sends an ajax request to the server to record the vote (hence the instant visual feedback). Normally that request completes in a reasonable time and all is well. Sometimes there's an error processing the request (either an HTTP error — e.g., something went wrong — or a logic error where the server rejected the vote); when that happens, you see an error message and the code reverts the display of the vote (because it wasn't registered on the server).

In Stack Exchange's case, they use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library in their JavaScript code. To give you an idea just how easy this is, here's the client side of a straight-forward ajax call using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:    "/path/to/server/resource",
    method: "POST",
    data:   {action: "voteup"},
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something with the successful response from the server,
        // which can send back data
    },
    error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Do something with the error that occurred
    }
 });
```

The server side just responds to the POST operation in whatever way makes sense.

That example is using jQuery, but there are lots of other JavaScript libraries that also make ajax really simple, such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library),  [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). jQuery is currently (by far) the most popular library for browser-based JavaScript tasks, but it's not the only one.

#### When you're just looking at things

I can only speak to this from the outside, but I expect Stack Exchange uses any of several "[comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)" techniques (web sockets, long polling, hidden `iframes`, etc.).

I expect [web sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) are the first choice. For instance, if I open a question using Chrome with the Network tab open, I see a request to `ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/`, and `ws` is [one of the two schemes covered by the wire protocol RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-3) associated with web sockets (the other being `wss`, the SSL-secured version). The joy of web sockets is that they *officially* and robustly allow persistent two-way communication between the client and server, allowing the server to push data to the client as appropriate.

Web sockets are [reasonably well supported now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) with the glaring omission of IE9 and earlier, so SE presumably falls back to one or more of the older techniques mentioned in the above link for browsers that don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

for me, replacing Entity Framework for Dapper worked very well. There was a significant increase in speed.

Comment: He's asking about client side functionality, not database specifics.

Comment: @Dante, Ali_dotNet knows it is AJAX (he said it in comments) and he is wondering why it could be so fast (besides that he is asking for an implementation). I know 'from database to application' is only part of a complete solution. My answer refers to the speed part of his question.